# Does Anyone Know This Error? React-Native

Tags: react-native

**I am developing React-Native Android application. I get this line when debugging. I wonder why ?**

Nobody answers. Two days passed. Help me

React-native Android Debugger Error Code 712 and 303

[image: Error image view]

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      
      {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "attach"
      },
      {
        "command": "npm start",
        "name": "Run npm start",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal"
      },

      {
        "name": "Debug macOS",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "macos"
      },

      {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android"
      },
      
  
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try to `run-android` from the command line, so you can see the error output from react-native.